# Can I set the height of a div to be flexible?

Tags: html, css

I hope this isn't too vague of a question, but I feel like I'm running into a brick wall, so I'd really appreciate any and all feedback.

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is create a simple webpage, wherein the content is maintained by someone else (who has very little coding knowledge).  My thought was to set up a page with a big frame in the middle, and to have tabs up top that would change the content in the frame.  (This way, the person who maintains the page will only need to worry about the individual pages that are displayed in the frame; they'll never have to make changes to the main webpage itself.)  So far, I've gotten this to mostly work pretty well.

The problem I'm having is with the height of the frame.  More accurately, I'm having a problem with the div it's inside of.  I'd like it to be adjustable - based on the height of the content it's pulling in - but I can only seem to set the height manually.  The reason I want it adjustable is because the content it's pulling in for each tab is going to vary.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you may have... even if it's to tell me to try another solution altogether.  My main goal here is to create something that can be maintained by someone who doesn't really know any html.  I figured using a frame would be perfect, since they could update that piece in Word, but there may be some other method I'm not thinking of.  I'm open to all suggestions.

*edit: Here's some sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Indexfiles\style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper" style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="menubar" style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;">
                                     <a href="Indexfiles/iframe1.htm" target="Mainframe"><div id="tab"><h6>Tab 1
        </h6></div></a><a href="Indexfiles/iframe2.htm" target="Mainframe"><div id="tab"><h6>Tab 2
        </h6></div></a><a href="Indexfiles/iframe3.htm" target="Mainframe"><div id="tab"><h6>Tab 3
        </h6></div></a><a href="Indexfiles/iframe4.htm" target="Mainframe"><div id="tab"><h6>Tab 4
        </h6></div></a><a href="Indexfiles/iframe5.htm" target="Mainframe"><div id="tab"><h6>Tab 5
        </h6></div></a><a href="Indexfiles/iframe6.htm" target="Mainframe"><div id="tab"><h6>Tab 6
        </h6></div></a>
    </div><br />

    <div id="maincontent">
        <iframe src="Indexfiles/iframe1.htm" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="Mainframe"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with some code that you have? So we can see the situation. Perhaps a JsFiddle?

Comment: the height of a div IS flexible, to the extent and limit of it's parent container(s), if all parents have no explicit height set, the contents of the div should flow as high as needed

Comment: I think you can try the `min-height` property, if the content is small, the div will have `min-height`, if the content is large enough, the div will grow accordingly to contain the content.

Comment: @CTravel, I've added some code, but I'll admit I'm not familiar with JsFiddle.

fnostro, that was my thought as well, but I can't get it to work no matter what I try.

King King, I've tried that as well.  No luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you use iframe you can dynamically adjust the size of the iframe to fit the content using javascript as follows:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById(iFrameId);
    iframe.width = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetWidth;
    iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
```

**Edit:**

You can try to see if this will work:

```
<script>
   function resizeIFrame() {
      var iframe = document.getElementById("MainFrame");
          iframe.width = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetWidth;
          iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
   }
</script>

<div id="maincontent">
   <iframe id="MainFrame" onload="resizeIFrame();" src="Indexfiles/iframe1.htm" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" name="Mainframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

This is what my iframe*.htm files looks like as an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>iframe</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    padding:0px;
                    margin:0px;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                    float:left;
                    border:1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="float:left; width:160px; height:500px;">Frame</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Important:** when testing this you must run these files through a web server and have the files in the same domain otherwise your browser will block the request due to security issues.
If you have Chrome installed you will see the following error message when you view the javascript console:
[image]

Comment: This may be exactly what I need, but can you tell me how to implement it?  I think I must have left my brain at home today.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't working either.  I even got rid of the css file, just to make sure that wasn't somehow interfering, but it still doesn't work.  The height of the div is pretty small and it doesn't expand for the content.

Comment: @Mike try using iframe.contentWindow.innerHeight and iframe.contentWindow.innerWidth instead?

Comment: Scratch that! Might could use iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight though

Comment: @Mike Does the body tag in your iframe*.htm files have a `float:left;` style setting? Setting this worked for me.

Comment: No difference there either, @chrisgonzalez.

Comment: @Mike http://jsfiddle.net/n2DMz/ I'm able to retrieve a little iframe's scrollHeight, no luck for you?

Comment: @WitHeld, no - I've left those files as plain as possible for now.

Comment: @Mike try setting the float setting and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Mike, another thing that I just thought of is are you running this code through a web server reguest? If not then this might be your problem because the browsers cannot determine the iframe's domain and are therefore blocking the access to the iframe's content.

Comment: @WitHeld, I tried the float setting like you suggested and tried your example as well.  I've never used JSFiddle before, but I gave it a shot, and it's still giving me the same type of result.  Is there some little piece I'm missing? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EPqj8/)

Comment: @Mike, I think the fiddle does not work because the iframe*.htm files do not exist for that fiddle. When you run your main htm file are you simply double clicking it or do you run it in a web server and go to something like http://localhost/index.htm?

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm running this right from my desktop.  Everything is local and it's still giving me the same exact result in JSFiddle as it does on my desktop (with respect to the height).  Any chance you could give me an example in JSFiddle that shows it working?

Comment: BTW, I do appreciate your taking the time to help.  Thank you.  I hope I don't sound ungrateful at all.

Comment: @Mike, sorry for posting again so late. I am not sure if one can reference additional HTML files other than the main one in a jsFiddle. Onother thing you can try is if you are using Windows then I suggest you install [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper) and put your files under the www directory (by default that would be C:\wamp\www). Start the wamp server and go to `http://localhost` in your browser and continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the div has an id, it's height can be updated in an included css file.

your_page.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_style.css" /> 
<div id="your_frame">
[Frame Contents]
</div>
```

your_style.css:

```
#your_frame{
  height: 40px // Just tell your developers to change this number (they'll never have to open the html file).  Also, if you have google chrome, you can fiddle with this number in the Developer tools.
}
```

Depending on the scenario, you can use javascript to set the height more intelligently.

**EDIT:**
Here's an approach that requires even less maintenance:
The div inside of your html page:

```
<div id="your_frame">
    <div id="your_contents">
    Contents Go Here
    <br>    
    <br> More Contents
    <br> Even more contents
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#your_frame{
    border-style:solid; # <-- using a solid border so you can play with these code chunks in JSfiddle.net
    #height:100px;     #  <-- omit the height (let the div auto-size/auto-wrap the contents)
}

#your_contents {
     #height:100px;   #  <-- omit the height (let the div auto-size/auto-wrap the contents)
     margin-top:10px; #  <-- I think what you're really after is the margin adjustments
     margin-bottom:10px;
     margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: might wanna change that to a #your_frame :)

Comment: Thank you, @RichS.  I know that works if I set the height as a static number, but I'd really like the frame to adjust itself based on the contents it pulls in.

Answer (score 0):

By default a div will automatically extend to the height of its parent container. Changes in this behavior often relate the the **position** property of its children. For instance if all of a divs children are absolutely positioned the height of the div will be at its default height. I don't have an example of what you are doing so I can only guess at the cause of your issue.

**Alternatively**, if you are open to alternatives. The scenario that you present is typically solved by the use of Content Management Systems. You would just need to customize the look and feel for your purposes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_content_management_system